# How to serve daily precomputed predictions in aws sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use Sagemaker to serve precomputed predictions. The predictions are in the following format in a python dictionary.

```
customer_group prediction
1              50
2              60
3              25
4              30
...
```

Currently the docker [serve API code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container/decision_trees/predictor.py) goes to s3 and downloads the data daily.

The problem is that downloading the data blocks the api from responding to the Sagemaker [health endpoint calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html#your-algorithms-inference-algo-ping-requests).

This a case study of [how zappos did it](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/zappos-case-study/) using Amazon DynamoDB. However, is there a way to do it in Sagemaker?

Where and how can I add the s3 download function to avoid interrupting the health check?

Could this work? -> https://github.com/seomoz/s3po
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-email-support

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ping', methods=['GET'])
def ping():
    """Determine if the container is working and healthy. In this sample container, we declare
    it healthy if we can load the model successfully."""
    health = ScoringService.get_model() is not None  # You can insert a health check here

    status = 200 if health else 404
    return flask.Response(response='\n', status=status, mimetype='application/json')

@app.route('/invocations', methods=['POST'])
def transformation():
    """Do an inference on a single batch of data. In this sample server, we take data as CSV, convert
    it to a pandas data frame for internal use and then convert the predictions back to CSV (which really
    just means one prediction per line, since there's a single column.
    """
    data = None

    # Convert from CSV to pandas
    if flask.request.content_type == 'text/csv':
        data = flask.request.data.decode('utf-8')
        s = StringIO.StringIO(data)
        data = pd.read_csv(s, header=None)
    else:
        return flask.Response(response='This predictor only supports CSV data', status=415, mimetype='text/plain')

    print('Invoked with {} records'.format(data.shape[0]))

    # Do the prediction
    predictions = ScoringService.predict(data)

    # Convert from numpy back to CSV
    out = StringIO.StringIO()
    pd.DataFrame({'results':predictions}).to_csv(out, header=False, index=False)
    result = out.getvalue()

    return flask.Response(response=result, status=200, mimetype='text/csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not call [batch transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-batch.html) instead and let AWS do the heavy lifting.

You can either schedule to be completed every day, or instead trigger it manually.

After this use either API Gateway with a Lambda function or CloudFront to display the results from S3.

Comment: A persistent endpoint is needed. The training and writing to S3 is done. The problem is how to serve the data.

Comment: Hi,

I have amended answer to include the displaying via persistent endpoint

Comment: Thanks mokugo! Do you have more resources on how to serve a S3 table through gateway lambda // cloudfront?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html or https://medium.com/tensult/creating-aws-cloudfront-distribution-with-s3-origin-ee47b8122727

Comment: lambda doesnt solve the issue because it just moves things from one bucket to the other. Also, a CDN is overkill. Thank you Chris :) The goal is to have a microservice that serves an inmemory dictionary using sagemaker.